# Widget ListView loading view

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to display a dynamic list on a widget and so far i've been able to display my 3 headers (which are simply textview inside a linearlayout) but for my items (2 textview in one linearlayout inside another linear layout) the view displays Loading... instead of the content (a task label).

I've already bumped getViewTypeCount to 2 in my RemoteViewsFactory to match the number of views returned by the getViewAt.

I can't figure out what is wrong inside this layout that would cause a problem:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
android:id="@+id/widget_item"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:paddingLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="•"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone reading this, i have been able to solve it by suppressing the style attribute